# MATLAB solver, calling on pre-defined variables within the equations

Tags: matlab, solver

So I'm wondering how to input pre-defined variables into the equations themselves.

Here's the code.

```
function[A, B, C] = A_B_C_problem_generalized(lambda_1, lambda_2, mu_1, mu_2, gamma_1, gamma_2)

clear
clc
syms a1 a2 a4 b1 b2 b4 c1 c2 c4

[a1, a2, a4, b1, b2, b4, c1, c2, c4] = ...
solve('a1 + a4 = lambda_1 + lambda_2', ...
'a1*a4 - a2^2 = lambda_1 * lambda_2', ...
'b1 + b4 = mu_1 + mu_2', ...
'b1*b4 - b2^2 = mu_1 * mu_2', ...
'c1 + c4 = gamma_1 + gamma_2', ...
'c1*c4 - c2^2 = gamma_1 * gamma_2', ...
'c1 = a1 + b1', ...
'c2 = a2 + b2', ...
'c4 = a4 + b4');
...
```

How could I go about doing this? The lambda's, mu's, and gamma's are supposed to be numbers you put in.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, the correct approach was to not be using strings. Instead, convert it into a problem of finding roots, which the solver does on its own if you move everything onto one side of the equation...

```
syms a1 a2 a4 b1 b2 b4 c1 c2 c4

[a1, a2, a4, b1, b2, b4, c1, c2, c4] = ...
solve(a1 + a4 - (lambda_1 + lambda_2), ...
a1*a4 - a2^2 - (lambda_1*lambda_2), ...
b1 + b4 - (mu_1 + mu_2), ...
b1*b4 - b2^2 - (mu_1*mu_2), ...
c1 + c4 - (gamma_1 + gamma_2), ...
c1*c4 - c2^2 - (gamma_1*gamma_2), ...
c1 - a1 - b1, ...
c2 - a2 - b2, ...
c4 - a4 - b4)
```

is the way to go.